# How create with ffmpeg a *.mov file which could be opened in default WMP?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, mov

How create MOV, QuickTime Movie (.mov) which could be opened in default Windows Media Player? Actually, smth. like this: http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/video/mov/example.mov

I have files MPEG-1 or MPEG-2 and want to convert it with ffmpeg to the mov. Sure, I can write smth. like this:

`ffmpeg -i in.mpg -level 3.1 -vformat mpeg4 -qscale 1 -f mov out.mov`

...and this will be Ok. But I need resulting file which will be correct MOV but, may be, without mpeg4 in it and played in WMP without installing any additional codecs

Comment: Does your WMP play H.264 video?

Comment: No. Just default WMP. But it plays http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/video/mov/example.mov